# jquery ui drag element without keeping mouse button down (follow the cursor)

Tags: jquery-ui, mouse, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to drag an element without keeping the mouse button down.

The behavior I would like is :

1. I click on a draggable item
2. Drag my item without keeping mouse left click down : just follow the mouse as a cursor
3. I click on a droppable container to confirm and append my item

I am able to simulate this behavior if I add an `alert` box durring the start event.

```
    start : function(){
        alert('test')
    },
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QvRjL/103/

How is it possible to code this behavior without the alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good solution about this problem : [Trigger Click-and-Hold Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445375/trigger-click-and-hold-event)

http://jsfiddle.net/VXbpu/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/vPruR/70/

```
var click = false;

$(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (click == true) {
        $('#your_div_id').css({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    }
});

$('#your_div_id').click(function() {
    click = !click;
    return false;
});

$('html').click(function() {
    click = false;
});
```