# Trigger function on user click&hold [chrome extension]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How do you trigger a function when user click and hold on any page in a chrome extension?
Here is what I'm using and it's not working:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Harvix extension",
    "description": "Shortcut to search on Harvix",
    "version": "0.0.1",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
             "js": ["jquery.js", "core.js"]
        }
    ],

    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

**core.js**

```
var timeout;
function open(text) {
    $('#myElement').mousedown(function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(null, 1000);
    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
    alert('hello');
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: open(window.getSelection().toString())});
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger Click-and-Hold Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445375/trigger-click-and-hold-event)

Comment: i think that question is about darg&drop in jquery

Comment: If you choose not to utilize jQuery in your extension, then the same method applies, but you will still need to roll your own Click and Drag methods, I gathered though that the `"js": ["jquery.js", "core.js"]` line in your code means you have the jQuery library at your disposal to make your life easier, may as well use it

Comment: i think you misunderstood me,I wanted to be able to detect click and hold, not click and drag

Comment: sorry, my comment meant to say `Hold`, not `Drag`. If you specifically want to detect a hold (without any movement), then calculating the x/y position before and after release will ensure Click & Drag events are ignored.

Comment: ok sorry, thanks for the comments

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37813/discussion-between-pixeladed-and-leon-stafford)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `core.js`, replace this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: open(window.getSelection().toString())});
});
```

With this:

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function () {

    open(window.getSelection().toString());        

});
```

That will overcome the issue of not being able to target the `chrome.browserAction` object within a content script.