# is it possible fire an event on button press and hold in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on a project in which i want a menu to appear on screen whenever it is touched and hold. So I want to know that just like button click and hover property in CSS is there any way to implement click and hold property, if no then how it can be done using javascript or jquery.

thanks

Comment: Capture the mousedown event and start a timeout.  If you don't get mouseup before that is complete then show the menu.  If you do get mouseup before that's complete then clear the timeout.  Once you've got code with errors then let us know and we can help you :)

Comment: isn't that what `:active` is for?

Comment: @Paulie_D, I was thinking the same thing, but `:active` won't work in IE if you are trying to style elements other than the active element.

Comment: @Archer is correct i think i should surely give it a try, but as far as for using :active, it does not support the hold property, I think it can only be done with the help of javascript

Comment: @DerekS :active is just for click events i think not for hold.. or maybe i am wrong. :)

Comment: @DaljeetDhaliwal here is the spec: `The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.` Of course, that doesn't mean browsers follow it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery, a combination of `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mouseleave`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALb3G/)

```
<button class="testHold">click and hold me</button>
<div class="tracker"></div>


$('.testHold').mousedown(function() {
    $('.tracker').html("holding holding holding");
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    $('.tracker').text('free as a bird...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no truly native way to accomplish this. You can check out this solution for a good workaround using jquery's draggable plugin.

[Trigger Click-and-Hold Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445375/trigger-click-and-hold-event)