# drag drop with scroll in mobile issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

check code http://liveweave.com/ExmKkE
[image]

i have both scrollable and droppable object , problem i that when i try to scroll in mobile device object starts dragging how to stop dragging behaviour when scrolled

**see below link :**http://liveweave.com/ExmKkE

is it possible to stop vertical drag drop or any better way to overcome it

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Quo.js](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) , it will fit your needs. Probably you will use the `hold` method.
Or if you don't want to use, this answer might be the best for you. [Trigger Click-and-Hold Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445375/trigger-click-and-hold-event)

Comment: still could not figure out if i use quo.js have to changle whole code .2 nd example could not understand

Comment: Quo.js will change only your methods that what you want to do, like double tap, hold, zoom in, zoom out etc. From the second example, I thought you we're using jquery drag n drop. So I thought you'd use the same method(draggable).

Comment: could not figure out ,how to use 2nd option , can u edit liveweave