# Dragging an item without mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery-ui to drag items from one list to another, but I would like to be able to drag an element without having to press the mouse, that is, we press the mouse once and the element is clicked on the cursor and when pressing again it is deposited The item in the position that the cursor is located.

I do not know if it can be done with Jquery-ui Draggable or Sortable by Jquery-ui. So I appreciate your help.

Comment: Tough one!  You'll have to monkey-patch jQuery UI to do this.  I'm going to give it a shot!

Comment: Hello @StevenMoseley, I've been looking at the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445375/trigger-click-and-hold-event, but I can not get it to work. It's exactly what I want but using Sortable by Jqueryu-ui

Comment: yeah, unfortunately, that answer is not using jQuery UI components.  You'll have to hack jQuery UI to do what you want, using what I started building below.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer**, but it's likely the start of one.

I was able to toggle draggable status and pull the underlying widget on click.

Unfortunately, I can't find the trigger to "start" and "stop" the drag on mousemove.

I don't have time to continue working on this.  Hopefully someone can pick up where I left off:

```
$('div.draggable-text').draggable({ disabled: true }).data('draggable', false);

$('div.draggable-text').on('click', function (event) {
    // Toggle status
    var draggable = !$(this).data('draggable');
    $(this).data('draggable', draggable);
    $(this).draggable(draggable ? 'enable' : 'disable');

    // Get widget
    var widget = $(this).data("ui-draggable");
    console.log(widget);

    // Trigger widget start or stop event
    if (draggable) {
        //widget._mouseStart(event);
        widget._trigger("start", event);
    } else {
        //widget._mouseStop(event);
        widget._trigger("stop", event);
    }
});
```