# jquery… when input range is hovered… force -webkit-slider-thumb to follow mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to force -webkit-slider-thumb to follow mouse when user hovers over input range?

```css
body {background: #f6f6f6;}

input[type="range"]{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  width:100%;
  height:190px;
  background: teal;}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  width:10px;
  height:190px;
  background: white;
  opacity: .5;}

input:focus {outline: none;}
```

```html
<input type="range"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger Click-and-Hold Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445375/trigger-click-and-hold-event)

Comment: It kinda seems to be in the same field… but I cannot get it to work… so I changed my question a little.