# Attach "dragstart" event to "mouseup" to obtain draggable experience

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

Looking for a solution to drag an element after the "mouseup" event.

As you know dragging occurs when it recieves "mousedown" and "mousemove" events.

How can I achieve dragging with the "mouseup" event? (When click is realised)?

https://codepen.io/pklauzinski/pen/rxroyL

```
// Implement drag and drop for the image
$('.box').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $window = $(window),
        mouseX = e.pageX,
        mouseY = e.pageY,
        width = $this.outerWidth(),
        height = $this.outerHeight()
        elemX = $this.offset().left + width - mouseX,
        elemY = $this.offset().top + height - mouseY;

    e.preventDefault();
    $window.on('mousemove.drag', function(e2) {
        $this.offset({
            left: e2.pageX + elemX - width,
            top: e2.pageY + elemY - height
        });
    }).one('mouseup', function() {
        $window.off('mousemove.drag');
    });
});
```

Comment: The question is why? This is unexpected behaviour for most users, and how would you stop dragging?

Comment: I would stop dragging on "mousedown".

Comment: But when the mouse is released again it's a click, and the dragging is back on. It seems weird to have something be always draggable, unless when the mouse button is pressed.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518371/jquery-ui-drag-element-without-keeping-mouse-button-down-follow-the-cursor the solution in the answer to that question worked for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ui drag element without keeping mouse button down (follow the cursor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518371/jquery-ui-drag-element-without-keeping-mouse-button-down-follow-the-cursor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the `$('.box').on('click', function(e) {` method... that could make it, but keep in mind you would have to add an other on click or doubleclick to disable, also, it's quite a weird behaviour

Sample explanation of what I mean

```
// Implement drag and drop for the image
$('.box').on('click', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      $window = $(window),
      mouseX = e.pageX,
      mouseY = e.pageY,
      width = $this.outerWidth(),
      height = $this.outerHeight()
      elemX = $this.offset().left + width - mouseX,
      elemY = $this.offset().top + height - mouseY;

  e.preventDefault();
  $window.on('mousemove.drag', function(e2) {
      $this.offset({
          left: e2.pageX + elemX - width,
          top: e2.pageY + elemY - height
      });
  }).one('mousedown', function() {
      $window.off('mousemove.drag');
  });
});
```

This is how I would do it though

```
// Implement drag and drop for the image
$('.box').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      $window = $(window),
      mouseX = e.pageX,
      mouseY = e.pageY,
      width = $this.outerWidth(),
      height = $this.outerHeight()
      elemX = $this.offset().left + width - mouseX,
      elemY = $this.offset().top + height - mouseY;

  e.preventDefault();
  $window.on('mousemove.drag', function(e2) {
      $this.offset({
          left: e2.pageX + elemX - width,
          top: e2.pageY + elemY - height
      });
  }).one('click', function() {
      $window.off('mousemove.drag');
  });
});
```